# How many games does the UNC basketball team play as part of their regular season schedule?

Tags: basketball, collegiate, schedule

How can UNC have 32 basketball games in their [2016-2017 regular season schedule](http://www.goheels.com/SportSelect.dbml?SPID=12965&SPSID=668157&SITE=UNC&DB_OEM_ID=3350)?

I thought the absolute max was 31 and everywhere I check online it shows the max to be 31<sub>[(1)](http://www.bloggingthebracket.com/2015/7/9/8916893/2015-16-college-basketball-early-season-tournaments-exempt-background)</sub>. This [article](http://www.momentummedia.com/articles/cm/cm1406/bbtwoinfour.htm) explains this phenomenon:

> Under the new rules [instituted in 2006], teams can play either 29 regular season games or
>   27 regular season games plus no more than four games in one multi-team
>   tournament for a **maximum of 31 games**. Conference and other postseason
>   tournaments do not count against the limit. Before the change, teams
>   were limited to 28 games, with exempt multi-team events counting as
>   one of those 28 contests.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the game against Chaminade is exempt from the 31 game maximum due to an NCAA rule about playing games in Hawaii.

[Here is a link giving information about that.](http://www.goheels.com/ViewArticle.dbml?SPSID=668156&SPID=12965&DB_LANG=C&SITE=UNC&DB_OEM_ID=3350&ATCLID=211074189)

> The opener against Chaminade is in part made possible because of an NCAA rule regarding the University of Hawaii, which sometimes has trouble scheduling home games. NCAA rules permit a team playing in the Maui Inviational to play a game at Hawaii as essentially a "free" game that does not count against the maximum; that free game is why the Tar Heels can afford to play Division II Chaminade in the Maui opener.

[And here is a link with the rule, although not from an NCAA source](http://bloximages.chicago2.vip.townnews.com/messenger-inquirer.com/content/tncms/assets/v3/editorial/0/05/00553ff4-0cf8-11e3-b8a2-001a4bcf887a/52191b8e6b611.pdf.pdf)

> 17.3.6.7 Once-in-Four-Years Exemption – Contests in Hawaii, Alaska, Puerto Rico
>   or Canada. Once every four years, an institution may exempt from its maximum contest limits a
>   maximum of four contests during a single trip to Hawaii, Alaska, Puerto Rico or Canada, either
>   against or under the sponsorship of an active member institution located in Hawaii, Alaska,
>   Puerto Rico or Canada, by a member institution located outside the area in question.

Comment: +1.  That explains the [Wisconsin](http://www.uwbadgers.com/schedule.aspx?path=mbball) and [Indiana](http://iuhoosiers.com/schedule.aspx?path=mbball) schedules, because each of those teams also played in Hawaii this year and have 32 games.

Comment: I think it's also possible the ACC-Big Ten challenge game is being excluded (17.3.6.5 Once-in-Three-Years Exemption – Conference Challenge Event).  Either one is a possibility.

Comment: Actually, I think it is either the ACC-Big Ten challenge, or the UHawaii game - *not* the Chaminade game. The Chaminade game is one of the Maui Invitational games itself, not an extra exception.  UHawaii on the other hand was not part of the exception.

Comment: Also not sure about your bylaws; they say 2013, but they seem more outdated than the ones I see from 2015 that suggest they were 2005 changes (consistent with what I've read elsewhere).  The "once in four years Hawaii" exception was pre-2006, from what I've read, and was simplified in the 2006+ bylaws.

Comment: @BenMiller Wisconsin has 31 games scheduled (the first game on that list was not an official game, and the MSU game is listed twice 2/25 and 2/26, but ESPN confirms that is a mistake).

Comment: @BenMiller Similarly, Indiana has two games listed for Northwestern on those same days (2/25 and 2/26) which are not actually two games on ESPN's schedule.  I wonder if there's some big ten thing that weekend that is causing them to have two potential dates.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for the info.  It is odd that they have games listed twice on their schedules.

Answer (score 3):

The game at the University of Hawaii (not Chaminade) on Nov. 18 is likely the source of the 32nd game.  From the [2015-16 bylaws](http://grfx.cstv.com/photos/schools/usc/genrel/auto_pdf/2015-16/misc_non_event/NCAA_Division_I_Manual.pdf) (the most recent I can find):

> 17.3.5.3 Annual Exemptions
>
> > (f) Regular-Season Contest Against Alaska/Hawaii Member. One regular-season game in Hawaii or
> >     Alaska versus a member institution located in that state; (Adopted: 1/9/96 effective 8/1/96)

The game against Chaminade is part of the 4-game multi-team event exemption (17.3.5.1.1 Qualifying Regular-Season Multiple-Team Event) for the Maui Invitational.  Those three games, plus the "extra" game played earlier against Chatanooga, make up their four-game exemption.

H/t to GB11 for pointing the right direction (the right part of the bylaws).